# Различное отображение размера шрифта

Tags: android-textview, android

Ребята, возникла проблема.
// Или так и должно быть.

Создал активность с настройками. Дал возможность выставлять размер шрифта. Выбирать можно из спинера и сразу же смотреть на результат. Выбранный размер сохраняется в SharedPreferences. 
Затем читается оттуда значение и через textView.setTextSize(variableFromSharedPreferences) применяется. Все работает, но беспокоит отображение.

В textView, что в SettingsActivity, шрифт отображается нормально, а в других textView проекта он намного меньше выходит. 
К примеру, размер 15 в настройках (textView в SettingsActivity) соответствует 25 в остальных textView. То есть на других экранах он уменьшен сильно.

Что не так может быть?

Comment: Не должно быть проблем, проверь все внимательно, выведи логи.

Comment: А в каких единицах размер шрифта устанавливается? Насколько я помню, гугл рекомендует в "sp".

Comment: Я сохраняю простое int число и устанавливаю его тоже простым int'ом.

Сохраняю так:
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_FONT_SIZE, fontSizeKey);
editor.apply();

Читаю и устанавливаю так:
Integer fontSize = mSettings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_FONT_SIZE, -1);
display_1.setTextSize(fontSize);

Comment: Так же проблема в отображении "жирным" выделением. 
В разметке xml указал, что текст в textView будет bold, но после установки textSize программно выделение "жирным" не работает.

Comment: Проверил через LogCat. Короче, получается, что при передаче 
"18" размера шрифта "доходит" только "8".
при "25" - "15". Покопался в коде еще раз. И нашел такую вещь:

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
switch (position) {
case 0:
// fontSize 10
displayFontResualt.setTextSize(10);
fontSizeKey = 10;
break;
//...
case 15:
isplayFontResualt.setTextSize(25);
break;
}
fontSizeKey = position;
}

Получилось, что неправильно написал присвоение значения переменной.
Нужно же fontSizeKey = position + 10; 
В моем случае. 

Спасибо всем за отзывчивость.